# How to collect several Json responses and keep them outside the function?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have page with several JSON sources.

```
const results = [];

await page.on('response', async (response) => {    
    if (response.url() ){
        console.log('XHR response received'); 
        console.log(await response.json());
```

// how to collect data from  `response.json()` and pass to `results` array?

```
    } 
}); 

console.info(results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could just collect responses inside of the array:

```
const results = [];

await page.on('response', async (response) => {    
    if (response.url() && response.status() == 200){
        console.log('XHR response received'); 
        results.push(await response.json()); 
    } 
});

await page.goto(url, {waitUntil : 'networkidle0'});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: i got this reply: `ReferenceError: results is not defined`

Comment: Have you declared `results` outside of `page.on` function? (I've added it into the answer for clarity)

Comment: thank it worked. But now i have second problem. 
I make the click on the first page and want to collect response.json() when the second page is loading. So i stuck with this code :(

await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load');
await page.click(' #btnSearch');

const results = [];

await page.on('response', async (response) => {
    if (response.url() && response.status() == 200) {
        console.log('XHR response received');
        results.push(await response.json());
    }
});
await page.waitForSelector('#statusInfo');

console.log(results);

Comment: I suggest this: let's close this question as solved and open another one for another problem. That way it will be easier for us to read your code (it's close to unreadable in the comment now)

Comment: thanks. I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411119/how-to-collect-several-json-responses-after-i-made-page-click-event)